# Rep Privilege Descriptions are Blank

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges

I first noticed this issue on *Gaming* and it seems to be prevalent here as well.  The description of reputation privileges are blank.  The required rep, and personal rep percentage accumulated counters seem in order, but the rest of the content is mysteriously absent.  This is the first time I have really looked at the Privileges screen, so I'm not entirely sure this is not the norm, but it seems....odd to me.

---

[image: ?]

Comment: Yep - blank on Web apps too

Comment: +1 for freehand circle circling your freehand question mark.

Comment: Also, clicking `edit` gives me an error.

Comment: +1 just came here to post this after seeing it on Gaming as well then checking SO.

Comment: :p yep, fixed for me now after only a minute of me noticing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad, I fixed another bug with privs yesterday that was causing the wikis never to update on meta.

Unfortunately, the fix made the whole object non-serializable which caused serious performance problems, so all the code was commented out while I was sleeping.

Answer (score 0):

Until this is fixed you can look at the text through the `history` button if you like.

Comment: I don't see any history buttons...